# How to go back to parent route from child route in nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have two navigation menu, Artists and Albums on menu bar. I am using react_rotuer_dom v6

Here is the nested navigation structure.

1. Click Artists (Artist list will show) /artists
2. Click Artist (Album list will show)   /artists/artist/xxx
3. Click Album (Track list will show.    /artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy
4. Click Track (show lyric).             /artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy/track/zzz

So far my nested route is working as expected.
Now I want to go back to Album(3) from Track(4). There is a link Album to navigate back to Album. So how can I navigate this path /artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy from Track page. I can give absolute path /artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy, it is working.

But What if I click Albums route. I am using same pages for Albums, Album, and Track. Please see my rote below. Am I using correct way for nested route.

path

```
const paths = {
  home: "/",

  artists: "/artists",
  getArtists: () => `/artists`,
  artist: "artist/:artistId",
  getArtist : (artistId) => `artist/${artistId}`,

  albums: "/albums",
  getAlbums: () => `/albums`,
  album: "album/:albumId",
  getAlbum: (albumId) => `album/${albumId}`,

  track: "track/:trackId",
  getTrack: (trackId) => `track/${trackId}`,
};

export default paths;
```

Routes

```
<Routes>
    <Route path={paths.home} element={<HomePage />}></Route>

    <Route path={paths.artists}>
      <Route index element={<ArtistsPage />} />
      <Route path={paths.artist}>
        <Route index element={<AlbumsPage />} />
        <Route path={paths.album}>
          <Route index element={<AlbumPage />} />
          <Route path={paths.track} element={<TrackPage />}></Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>

    <Route path={paths.albums}>
      <Route index element={<AlbumsPage />} />
      <Route path={paths.album}>
        <Route index element={<AlbumPage />} />
        <Route path={paths.track} element={<TrackPage />}></Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
    
  </Routes>
```

Comment: Are you saying you are on a specific `/artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy/track/zzz` track page, and want to navigate back to the specific `/artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy"` album page that was the logical parent of the `TrackPage` that was being rendered? Where are these links being rendered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are asking how to navigate *back* to a parent route dynamically.

Just like the routes use relative paths to build up the route tree structure, the links can also use relative paths for linking.

[Link](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link)

> A relative `<Link to>` value (that does not begin with `/`) resolves
> relative to the parent route, which means that it builds upon the URL
> path that was matched by the route that rendered that `<Link>`. It may
> contain `..` to link to routes further up the hierarchy. In these
> cases, `..` works exactly like the command-line `cd` function; each
> `..` removes one segment of the parent path.

To navigate back two path segments to get from a specific track back to a specific album, use `../..`.

Example:

```
<Link to="../..">Back to parent</Link>
```

If the path is `"/artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy/track/zzz"` then clicking the link will navigate "up/back" two path segments to `"/artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy"`. Similarly, if the path is `"/artists/artist/xxx/album/yyy"` then clicking the same link will again navigate "up/back" two path segments to `"/artists/artist/xxx"`.

Comment: This was so clutch. I ended up using `navigate(".")` to go up to the parent route.

Comment: "." doesn't work for me.

Comment: @LCB Relative paths start with anything but `"/"`, so where you need to navigate to *relative* to the current path and where the link is rendered depends on your specific use case. If you like you can create a new post for your specific issue, and reference this post and what isn't working for you. If you do this, feel free to ping me again here in a comment with a link to the new post.

Comment: @LCB I believe `"."` will resolve to the current route. To navigate to the direct parent route, `navigate("..")` is what works for me.

Comment: The problem with  Link is that it reloads the page

Comment: @AntoninL The `Link` component doesn't reload the page. Do you really mean something else is happening?

Comment: @DrewReese you are totally right, I was convince that I needed to use a function like onClick={() => navigate('..')} but <Link> does the job. Sorry about that

Comment: @AntoninL No worries, glad to help. Were you the person that happened to recently vote on the answer? I've just edited it to update the link to the documentation so any votes that are "locked in" can be changed.  Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese but actually I can't make this work.
I'm on the page `/deposite/form/:id` and I want to go back to `/deposite/` using `<Link to="..">` but when I click this link I am redirected to `/`

Comment: @DrewReese thanks, I changed my vote

Comment: @AntoninL It depends on what route/path the `Link` is being rendered on. `".."` removes 1 path segment, so if the link is rendered on path segment `"/deposite"` (*maybe in a parent route/component*) then `".."` will go to `"/"`, but `"."` should take you to `"/deposite"`. In other words, these are all relative. Can you create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code we could take a look at?

Comment: @DrewReese okay, indeed I render `<Link>` in my `App.tsx` to make the link appear on every page so if I change `..` to `.` it stills go back to `/`. I'm gonna try to find a way to make this work (without adding a `<Link to='..'>` on every single page.

Comment: @AntoninL Is there any issue with using an absolute path like `to="/deposite"` to navigate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255047/discussion-between-antoninl-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a "goToParent" button on every page of your app you could render that in your `App.tsx`

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const {pathname} = location;
  
  return (
    ...
    <Link to={pathname.substring(0, pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))> 
      Parent page
    </Link>
    ...
  )
```